# WPF User Interface not updating without moving mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am  using background work to load some content but something really  odd is happening the UI  is not updating and  it just begin to  happen  suddenly,
here follows the code

here is the  button click

```
 public void CarregaPaginaCTeTomador(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ClassControleInstancia.CTeTomador == null)
        {
            ClassControleInstancia.CTeTomador = new Page_CTE_Tomador();
        }
        BackgroundWorker LoadPageWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        LoadPageWorker.DoWork += LoadPageWorker_DoWorkCteTomador;
        LoadPageWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LoadPageWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        LoadPageWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

here is the 1° background work

```
private void LoadPageWorker_DoWorkCteTomador(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Antes do DoEvents");
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        Console.WriteLine("Apos o DoEvents");
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _mainFrame.Navigate(ClassControleInstancia.CTeTomador);
            ClassControleInstancia.CTeTomador.RefreshContent();
        });
    }

private void LoadPageWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WaitNSeconds(80);
        FrameCurrentPage();

    }
```

Inside this ClassControleInstancia.CTeTomador.RefreshContent(); has another background work should this be the reason why the ui is getting stocked ?
Cause I am not seeing any problem  with the code I am  going mad cause I tried alread remove the bgwork but it still gets stocked.

the other bgwork is

```
private void CarregaGrid(int pagina, int quantidade, int TipoArquivo, int AscDesc, bool inognoreNot = false) //0 crescente 1 desc
    {
        //show the loader
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader_Abort.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader_text.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader_porgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        BackgroundWorker GridLoader = new BackgroundWorker();
        GridLoader.DoWork += GridLoader_DoWork;
        GridLoader.RunWorkerCompleted += GridLoader_RunWorkerCompleted;
        GridLoader.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

private void GridLoader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgUsers.Items.Refresh();
        ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ButtonsSelector config = new ButtonsSelector();
        config.OnViewStart(TipoArquivoOrdenacaoEnum.CTE_NaoTomador, botoesSelector(), "cte-nao-tomador");
    }

    private void GridLoader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
        {
            ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.Loader_percentage.Width = new GridLength(0);
        }));

        CurrentPage = GridParams.Pagina;
        CurrentMaxRows = GridParams.QuantidadePorPagina;
        ObjSenhaWebApi Senha = new ObjSenhaWebApi(Conexao.ARQBancoDeDados().BuscaSenhaWebApiUsuario());
        ObjPesquisaNotas PesquisaNotas = new ObjPesquisaNotas();
        PesquisaNotas.IdEmpresa = ClassControleInstancia.EmpresaSelecionada.EMP_SEQUENCIA_ORI;
        PesquisaNotas.Pagina = GridParams.Pagina;
        PesquisaNotas.QntdMostrar = GridParams.QuantidadePorPagina;
        PesquisaNotas.Ordenacao = GridParams.TipoArquivo;
        PesquisaNotas.CrescenteDecrescente = GridParams.IsAscDesc;
        PesquisaNotas._ObjListaParametrosNfeSaida = new ObjListaParametrosNfeSaida();
        PesquisaNotas._ObjListaParametrosNfeSaida.UsuarioId = Conexao.ARQBancoDeDados().BuscaSequenciaClienteOri();
        PesquisaNotas.tipoTomador = 1;

        #region CamposDaPesquisa

        P_ADICIONA_CAMPOS_PESQUISA(PesquisaNotas);

        #endregion

        int V_EMPRESA = 0;
        string V_NUMERO_NOTA = "";

        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => V_NUMERO_NOTA = EDT_NUMERO_NOTA.Text.Trim()));


        if (ClassControleInstancia.EmpresaSelecionada != null)
        {
            V_EMPRESA = ClassControleInstancia.EmpresaSelecionada.EMP_SEQUENCIA;
            string V_FORNECEDOR = "";
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => V_FORNECEDOR = CbFornecedor.Text.ToString()));

            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => dgUsers.ItemsSource = null));




            List<Cte> ListaNotas = ArquivarNfeRest.ArquivarNfeRest.BuscaNotaSaida<Cte>(Senha, PesquisaNotas);
            if (ListaNotas != null)
            {
                if (ListaNotas.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => nuvenzita_no_itens.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden));
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => nuvenzita_no_itens.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => nuvenzita_no_itens.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
            }
            //Colocar em negrito todos os matchs com a outra lista

            List<string> ListaNegrito = ClassControleListaNegrito.BuscaLista(ClassControleInstancia.EmpresaSelecionada.EMP_SEQUENCIA, TipoArquivoOrdenacaoEnum.CTE_NaoTomador, true).ValorLista;

            foreach (var item in ListaNotas)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in ListaNegrito)
                {
                    if (item2 == item.CteSequencia.ToString())
                    {
                        item.NEGRITO = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            ObjRetornoCount _ObjRetornoCount = ArquivarNfeRest.ArquivarNfeRest.BuscaQntdNotaSaida<Cte>(Senha, PesquisaNotas);
            int QntdPaginas = _ObjRetornoCount.QntdPaginas;
            int QntdNotas = _ObjRetornoCount.QntdTotal;


            //Retira aviso vermelho (confima letura)
            if (GridParams.IgnorarAlerta != true)
            {
                ClassDoReadNotification<Cte>.Verify();
                ClassControleInstancia.Notifications.IsCteNaoTomadorRead = 1;
                ClassControleInstancia.JanelaPrincipal.AlertaNovasNotas();
            }

            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                totalItensFiltrados = QntdNotas;
                itensNoFiltro = ListaNotas;
                if (VerificaSeTemFiltro() == 0)
                {
                    paginatorTotal.Content = "Nº Total Doctos: " + (QntdNotas);
                }
                else
                {
                    paginatorTotal.Content = "Nº Total Doctos Filtrados: " + (QntdNotas);
                }
                Pagenizer.getButtons(footer, QntdPaginas, CurrentPage, CurrentMaxRows, "cte-nao-tomador");


            }));
            //List<ObjSincronizados> ListaNotas = Conexao.ARQBancoDeDados().BuscaListaSincronizados(V_EMPRESA, V_NUMERO_NOTA, V_DATA_INICIAL, V_DATA_FINAL, V_FORNECEDOR);
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => dgUsers.ItemsSource = ListaNotas));
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                int tt = dgUsers.Items.OfType<Cte>().Where(x => x.MARCADO == true).Count();
                int ttAll = dgUsers.Items.OfType<Cte>().Where(x => x.MARCADO == true || x.MARCADO == false).Count();
                btCounter.Content = "Selecionados " + tt.ToString() + " de " + ttAll.ToString();
                headerCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
            }
            ));
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` in a WPF app? Never, **never** do that again! You screw up the dispatcher.